# Nodebox open GL Graph, size function not recognized. (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, nodebox

I am trying to use Nodebox Graph on Ubuntu and python 2.7.

So I got Nodebox OpenGL: http://www.cityinabottle.org/nodebox/

Nodebox Graph: https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph

I tried to run their basic example 1 :

```
graph = ximport("graph")

size(500, 500)

g = graph.create()

# Create some relations.
g.add_edge("roof"        , "house")
g.add_edge("garden"      , "house")
g.add_edge("room"        , "house")
g.add_edge("kitchen"     , "room")
g.add_edge("bedroom"     , "room")
g.add_edge("bathroom"    , "room")
g.add_edge("living room" , "room")
g.add_edge("sofa"        , "living room")
g.add_edge("table"       , "living room")

# Calculate a good layout.
g.solve()

# Apply default rules for node colors and size,
# for example, important nodes become blue.
g.styles.apply()

# Draw the graph, indicating the direction of each relation
# and the two nodes that get the most traffic.
g.draw(
    directed=True,
    traffic=1
)
```

That doesn't work because ximport is not defined, it is only define by nodebox, so instead I tried two things, first doing a normal import
    import graph
second putting the ximport function from nodebox in my code:

```
def ximport(library):
    from sys import modules
    library = __import__(library)
    library._ctx = modules[__name__]
    return library


graph = ximport("graph")


size(500, 500)

g = graph.create()

# Create some relations.
g.add_edge("roof"        , "house")
g.add_edge("garden"      , "house")
g.add_edge("room"        , "house")
g.add_edge("kitchen"     , "room")
g.add_edge("bedroom"     , "room")
g.add_edge("bathroom"    , "room")
g.add_edge("living room" , "room")
g.add_edge("sofa"        , "living room")
g.add_edge("table"       , "living room")
# Calculate a good layout.
g.solve()

# Apply default rules for node colors and size,
# for example, important nodes become blue.
g.styles.apply()

# Draw the graph, indicating the direction of each relation
# and the two nodes that get the most traffic.
g.draw(
    directed=True,
    traffic=1
)
```

That still doesn't work because now the function size is not recognized. If I just comment size out, I get the following error:

> ```
> self.x = _ctx.WIDTH - max.x*self.d - min_.x*self.d
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'WIDTH'

What do I do?

This question could be similar:

[Pydev Nodebox: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'WIDTH'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996530/pydev-nodebox-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-width)

but the given answer is not helpful at all to me.

Comment: '_ctx' in nodebox1 is basically the same as 'canvas' in nodeboxgl.  You could probably change your ximport to the one below .. things will probably break as the API is a little different though..  you could probably make wrap the changed APIs in ximport.. 

    def ximport(canvas, lib):
        library = __import__(lib)
        library._ctx = canvas
        return library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph
doesn't work for nodebox opengl, it is only compatible for nodebox 1 for mac so there is no easy fix. However, nodebox opengl has it's own interactive functions to it is possible to use them instead. Here is partial example code:

```
from nodebox.graphics import *
from nodebox.graphics.physics import Node, Edge, Graph

class GUI():
"""Draw and interact with the damn thing. 
"""
def __init__(self):
    """rawgraph is an instance of the RawGraph class
    The GUI allows to interact with it, i.e. view it and change it. 
    """
    #Layer.__init__(self) # unknown thing, might be necessary.
    #Buttons
    self.EXPLORE_F = "Explore Further"
    self.EXPLORE_D = "Explore Deeper"
    self.DELETE = "Delete"
    self.CLOSE = "CLOSE"
    self.BUTTONS = False #Are buttons showing?
    self.CBUTTON = False #Is Close button showing?


    self.nodes = []


    self.g = Graph()
    self.dragged =None
    self.clicked = None



    def add_node(self, name, root = False):
    self.nodes.append(name)
    self.g.add_node(id=name, radius = 5, root = root)


def add_edge(self,n1,n2,*args,**kwargs):
    self.g.add_edge(n1, n2, *args,**kwargs)


def explore_further(self,node_name):
    """action of explore further button
    """
    pass
def explore_deeper(self,node_name):
    """action of explore deeper button
    """
    pass
def delete_node(self,node_name):
    """action of delete button
    """
    pass

def close_canvas(self):
    """Close the canvas
    """
    canvas.clear()
    canvas.stop()

def add_close(self):
    """Add close button
    """
    self.g.add_node(self.CLOSE, radius = 10, fill=(1,0,0,0.2))
    self.g.add_edge(self.rawg.root, self.CLOSE, length=0.6)
    self.CBUTTON=True

def remove_close(self):
    """Remove the close button 
    """
    try:
        self.g.remove(self.g.node(self.CLOSE))

    except:
        pass
    self.CBUTTON=False

def add_buttons(self,node_name):
    """Add the buttons to change the graph
    """
    self.g.add_node(self.EXPLORE_F, radius = 6, fill=(0,1,0,0.5))
    self.g.add_node(self.EXPLORE_D, radius = 6, fill=(0,0,1,0.5))
    self.g.add_node(self.DELETE,radius=6, fill=(1,0,0,0.5))
    self.g.add_edge(node_name, self.EXPLORE_F, length=0.2)
    self.g.add_edge(node_name, self.EXPLORE_D, length=0.2)
    self.g.add_edge(node_name, self.DELETE, length=0.2)
    self.BUTTONS = True

def remove_buttons(self):
    """Remove the buttons to change the graph
    """
    try:
        self.g.remove(self.g.node(self.DELETE))
        self.g.remove(self.g.node(self.EXPLORE_D))
        self.g.remove(self.g.node(self.EXPLORE_F))
    except:
        pass
    self.BUTTONS=False


def draw(self):

    canvas.clear()
    background(1)
    translate(500, 500)

    # With directed=True, edges have an arrowhead indicating the direction of the connection.
    # With weighted=True, Node.centrality is indicated by a shadow under high-traffic nodes.
    # With weighted=0.0-1.0, indicates nodes whose centrality > the given threshold.
    # This requires some extra calculations.
    self.g.draw(weighted=0.5, directed=False)
    self.g.update(iterations=10)

    # Make it interactive!
    # When the mouse is pressed, remember on which node.
    # Drag this node around when the mouse is moved.
    dx = canvas.mouse.x - 500 # Undo translate().
    dy = canvas.mouse.y - 500
    #global dragged
    if canvas.mouse.pressed and not self.dragged:
        self.dragged = self.g.node_at(dx, dy)
        old_clicked = self.clicked
        try:
            self.clicked = self.dragged.id
        except: 
            self.clicked = None


        if self.clicked != None:   
            if self.clicked == self.DELETE:
                if old_clicked != None:
                    self.delete_node(old_clicked)
                    self.remove_buttons()
            elif self.clicked == self.EXPLORE_D:
                if old_clicked != None:
                    self.explore_deeper(old_clicked)
                    self.remove_buttons()
            elif self.clicked == self.EXPLORE_F:
                if old_clicked != None:
                    self.explore_further(old_clicked)
                    self.remove_buttons()
            elif self.clicked == self.CLOSE:
                self.remove_buttons()
                self.remove_close()
                self.close_canvas()
            else:
                self.remove_buttons()
                self.remove_close()
                self.add_buttons(self.clicked)

        else:
            if self.BUTTONS:
                self.remove_buttons()
            elif self.CBUTTON:
                self.remove_close()
            else:
                self.remove_buttons()
                self.add_close()



    if not canvas.mouse.pressed:
        self.dragged = None
    if self.dragged:
        self.dragged.x = dx
        self.dragged.y = dy


def start(self, distance = 30, force = 0.01, repulsion_radius=30):
    """Starts the GUI
    """
    #self.g.prune(depth=0)          # Remove orphaned nodes with no connections.
    self.g.distance         = distance   # Overall spacing between nodes.
    self.g.layout.force     = force # Strength of the attractive & repulsive force.
    self.g.layout.repulsion = repulsion_radius   # Repulsion radius.
    canvas.draw = self.draw
    canvas.size = 1000, 1000
    canvas.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':

gui = GUI()
gui.add_node("a")
gui.add_node("b")
gui.add_edge("a","b")

gui.start(distance=30, repulsion_radius=30)
```